# What type of caterpillar is this?

Tags: identification, bugs

I found a caterpillar in my garden in Johannesburg, South Africa. It is mostly black/brown, quite large, and has four white patches on its head. The tail has a small spotted white tip. It’s is about 10cm long
Here is an image:
[image: The Catepillar]
Should I kill it, or is it safe to let it free. Will it destroy my garden?

Comment: Can you add what size it is?

Comment: Looks to be in the Sphingidae family (Hornworms, Hawkmoths).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

African Death's Head Hawk moth, [*Acherontia atropos*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acherontia_atropos). The tail and head markings match. Last instar before making a cacoon.

Is it good? It will eat your potato or tomato leaves. It is nearly fully grown, maybe feed it some leaves and let it tunnel into soft dirt, and allow it to turn into a moth.

Wikipedia article says:

"Eggs are laid singly under old leaves of Solanaceae: potato especially, but also Physalis and other nightshades. However it also has been recorded on members of the Verbenaceae, e.g. Lantana, and on members of the families Cannabaceae, Oleaceae,[9] Pedaliaceae and others."